# Validation rule for Google Form input to avoid duplicate values in different input fields?

Tags: forms, validation

I'm using a Google Form to let parents register their students in our after-school club.  As we're 100% virtual (thanks, COVID-19!), parents must first sign up on a 3rd-part activity site, then create sub-accounts for their kids.

My Google form asks them to enter their *parent* username first, then later enter their kid's username on a second section of the form.

Despite the form instructions using a **BOLD CAPS** directive to enter their parent ID first, then their child's ID later, I have numerous respondents entering the same ID in both places.

Is there any way to use a validation rule to prevent them from doing this, i.e. (INPUT B) must not equal (INPUT A)?